# Freemarker single = in if statement

Tags: keycloak, freemarker

Keycloak uses Freemarker templates. [There you find](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/login/info.ftl#L3) single `=` in if-statements.

[Freemarker's documentation](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_if.html) tells me to use `==` in if-statements.

Keyclaok's templates seem to work. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is allowed in expressions, but deprecated. From the "Comparison" section of the expression documentation:

> To test two values for equality you use `==` (or `=` as a *deprecated* alternative)

See: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_comparison